# python script to read a log file to determine the list of URLs that were not found (404)

Tags: python, file-io, logfile

from the given log file, I need to find which URLs were not found (404)
Sample data from log file is:

Entry 1:

443623565414391809  2014-09-02T14:09:36  2014-09-03T00:48:42Z  4147981   demo-workablehr     54.198.230.235  Local3  Info    heroku/router  at=info method=GET path="/api/accounts/3" host=workabledemo.com request_id=73ffd4fc-c86c-41ca-a737-91da110fbc39 fwd="50.31.164.139" dyno=web.2 connect=5ms service=17ms status=404 bytes=444

Entry 2:

443623565414391810   2014-09-02T14:10:27     2014-09-03T00:48:42Z   4147981 demo-workablehr  54.198.230.235  Local7  Info    app/web.2   [e1af99e5-64b4-4228-8e23-d9b6bab84f80] [VISITOR #NEW] [GUEST]   [1m[35mAccount Load (1.2ms)[0m  SELECT  "accounts".* FROM "accounts"  WHERE (accounts.approval_status != 'blocked') AND "accounts"."id" = 3 LIMIT 1

Here the block () is 'ESC'

I understand that I need to open a file and read the content and look for status=404
How can I do this using python3 and the number of entries in the file are 30,000+

I tried this:

```
count404 = 0
with open('C:\\Users\\Zee\\Downloads\\testLog.txt','r') as f:
    for line in f:
        for word in line.split():
            count404 += 1
print(count404)
```

I am wondering if there is a better approach and if I take this approach then how to find the list of URLs which have status = 404

I am fairly new to python and to StackOverflow.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Why don't you try something and show us the code if you are getting difficulties? I suggest iterating through the logfile lines and select those lines containing (maybe with `in` operator) `"status=404"`

Comment: Also, welcome to SO. Take some time to review the help center for example here https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: You may edit your question further. It is not clear if you know how to do it in Python (or not), or why exactly you are asking for advice.

Comment: @progmatico I have edited the question, please let me know if that helps.

Comment: Don't split the lines in words, check `if "status=404" in line` and if so make further processing to extract what you want. Alternatively or in combination, as that is searchiing for text patterns, you might want to use `re`module (search with regular expressions) to extract the relevant parts in each line (for example using groups)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out in comments, regex is your best friend here,
here is the sample approach

```
import re
count=0
fl=open('C:\\Users\\Zee\\Downloads\\testLog.txt','r')
fillines=fl.readlines()
fl.close()
for i in fillines:
  if re.search(r'status=404',i):
    count+=1
```

to make a list of all the paths in logs having status as 404 we can again use regex

```
import re
count=0
lst=[]
fl=open('C:\\Users\\Zee\\Downloads\\testLog.txt','r')
fillines=fl.readlines()
fl.close()
for i in fillines:
  if re.search(r'status=404',i):
    count+=1
    path=re.search(r'path="[/\w+/]+"',fillines[0]).group(0)#get path using regex
    path=path.split("path=")[1] #since we only want the url
    path=path.replace('"','') #we dont want the quotes in log
    lst.append(path)#since we only want the url
```

Comment: Actually you can remove the `!=None` part

Comment: Thanks @progmatico

Comment: Thank you, guys! Now I am trying to figure out the way to record the list of URLs which have status = 404.
I appreciate your help!

Comment: so you want the list of all the paths for which status was 404.

Comment: @zee if thats all then you can mark the answer accepted. Otherwise you can post your further doubt.